# MySQL Create Query to Calculate future balances based on date from two tables

Tags: mysql

This is probably a simple one, but i can't figure it out.

I have data in two tables - 1) loans 2) repayments. I have been asked to produce a report to calculate the expected balances for each quarter based on our current portfolio.

So the approach i have taken is to take the SUM of all balances in the loans table (which gives our current balance) and the SUM of all expected payments in repayments table, and group by QUARTER(duedate) and YEAR(duedate) to subtract so that we can predict what will have been paid back on the loans at that time.

I copy my code below:

```
select sum(la.PRINCIPALBALANCE) - due.due as balance 
    ,due.q
    ,due.y
from loans la
join (select 
        PARENTACCOUNTKEY
        ,sum(principaldue) as due
        ,quarter(duedate) as q
        ,year(duedate) as y
    from repayment 
    group by quarter(duedate),year(duedate)) as due 
on la.encodedkey = due.parentaccountkey
group by due.q ,due.y
```

What I am hoping to see would be if we have the following simplified data:

Loans:

```
ID        principalbalance  
1         2500  
2         2500
```

Repayments:

```
Parentaccountkey    principaldue      duedate  
1                   500               Q1  
1                   500               Q2   
1                   500               Q3  
2                   100               Q1  
2                   100               Q2  
2                   100               Q2
```

I would want my table of results to show the following

```
Q1     4400 (which is the 2500 + 2500 principalbalance starting point, minus the 500 + 100 due in that month.
Q2     3800 (the 2500 + 2500, minus the 500 + 100 for Q1 and minus 500 + 100 for Q2)
Q3     3200 (the 2500 + 2500 minus the amounts for Q1, Q2 & Q3)
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data, the result you expect, and the result you're getting instead? Making a sqlfiddle would be most helpful.

Comment: @Barmar - sorry, my brain was a little addled last night, have added an example of expected results. I can also create an SQL fiddle if needed.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a subquery that calculates the running total of the `principaldue` for each quarter. Then join this with a query that calculates the total balance, so it can subtract it for each quarter.

```
SELECT duedate, total - running_due AS balance
FROM (SELECT a.duedate, SUM(b.principaldue) AS running_due
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT duedate
            FROM repayments) AS a
      JOIN repayments AS b ON b.duedate <= a.duedate
      GROUP BY a.duedate) AS x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(principalbalance) AS total
            FROM loans) AS y
ORDER BY duedate
```

There are other ways to calculate running totals, you can search for them and replace the subquery with what works best in your database.

Comment: thank you so much, i get the principal so will now tweak and look up other suggestions. Thank you!!!